# How to insert values into table from stored procedure inputs as well as temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
create procedure spname
    @ID varchar,
    @name varchar,
    @R xml
AS
BEGIN
    -- Getting values XML
    create table #Table
    (
       country varchar,
       status varchar
    )
```

I have to insert the values into a table based on the condition that if ID, Name which are from stored procedure input and country (from temp table) doesn't exists, then insert. I don't know exact syntax os how to join all these. However I tried below, but I reckon its wrong, I think I must some some looping technique like cursor?

```
DECLARE @Country VARCHAR;

SELECT @Country = C.Country 
FROM #Table C

INSERT INTO MyTable(Id, Name, Country)
VALUES (@Id, @Name, @Country)
FROM 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable mT
                      WHERE ID = @Id
                        AND Name = @Name
                        AND mt.country = C.country)
```

I am thinking there is wrong syntax in values as well as it will not serve my purpose as temp table contains a lot of values

I came up with a solution this way using cursor:

```
  DECLARE @country VARCHAR

    DECLARE CountryCur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT Country FROM #Temp

    OPEN CountryCur 

    FETCH NEXT FROM CountryCur INTO @Country

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MyTable(Id, Name, Country)
        VALUES (@id, @name, @Country)
        WHERE NOT IN (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable mT
                      WHERE mT.Id = @Id
                        AND mT.name = @name
                        AND mT.country = @Country)

        FETCH NEXT FROM CountryCur INTO @Country
        CLOSE CountryCur 
        DEALLOCATE CountryCur
```

However, it shows syntax error near where. Don't know whats wrong.

Comment: what does the xml parameter value look like ?

Comment: @M.Ali: XML you don't have to worry as I am converting that to a temp table. I haven't included that in here. So basically its from temp table and input parameters, I need to check if the row present in table. If not, then insert. So I made the solution above, not sure if it would serve purpose, but I also get syntax error near where. Any clue on my both concerns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well as you have mentioned you have the data in the #temp table coming from xml then it should be as simple as

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Id,Name,Country)
SELECT @Id, @Name, t.Country
FROM #Table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM MyTable mT
                  WHERE mt.ID = @Id
                    AND mt.Name = @Name
                    AND mt.country= t.country)
```

**No Cursor needed**

Comment: You are exactly right, but ID and Name in your where condition should also be with mt.? Correct?

Comment: All good, my SP executed :) Thanks a lot. In fact my Architect gave me the same code that you gave, but I was silly I didn't run it and was complicating it using cursor etc. Now I realized it was so simple. Thanks a lot again. Have a nice day

Answer (score -2):

You need to use SELECT...INTO instead of VALUES() as below:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(
            Id,
            Name,
            Country
        )
            select @ID, @Name, @Country
            WHERE not exists(select 1 from MyTable
                WHERE ID = @Id
                AND Name = @Name
                AND country in (Select country from #Temp))
```

Comment: Wow how come insert and select from same table? Your seems simple and I don't think its the solution I am after?

Comment: Oh mate, you live in Melbourne, right? It's not correct mate, sorry.

Comment: Based on the new information that #temp table contains more than one country, I edited my answer. Please check.